# When a close vote is clearly ridiculous, I see no obvious recourse. Should I even have one?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52066492/possible-to-use-extensions-methods-on-a-generic-enum-type-not-enum-value%20'here') on SO.  It instantly got a "not complete code" close vote.

If one looks at the first post in history, it's fully complete as code samples go.

I wanted to reject this close vote in some way, as I thought it was ridiculous, but couldn't find any means of reacting appropriately as I thought my post was already complete.

Was I wrong?  Am I missing something?

I suppose my question really is, was there any way I could have reacted other than "shrug"?

Comment: One close vote does nothing by itself (except if it's a duplicate by someone who holds a gold badge in the tags on the question). Taking the time to review your question and make sure it hits everything is definitely something you can do once you receive one close vote. There's not much more to it though. If you feel your question is okay, even after reviewing whatever guidance the close vote exposes, then leave it like it is :). (note: I haven't reviewed the question)

Comment: I don’t know C#, but the “missing MCVE” close reason is also used for an _unclear problem description_, i.e. your question should include things like your desired results, your actual results, including all errors, demonstrating your research and your attempts and explaining what precisely didn’t work.

Comment: Aside: You shouldn't answer your question in the question itself. If you ended up using something that differs from the given answers, that should be its own answer. (You don't have to accept it, even though it's yours.)

Comment: _@Dan_ Hmm, taking a quick look at your linked question, that seems to be about  a very basic syntactical problem, and you even missed to provide a MCVE as required. Be aware of the Meta-Effect as publishing here.

Comment: You could have asked how you can improve your post instead of a _"What where you thinking..."_ comment. Also that close reasons states you need a **Clear** problem statement and _"...doesn't want to work."_ is absolutely not clear. Are you getting errors? Does it run? Does it break down? Does it randomly blow up your pc?

Comment: Actually, if anyone tried the code I posted, it highlights the exact error.  It was a syntax error that I was hoping for clarification on.  I didn't even actually know the correct question to ask!!!  This is common, and I feel like I still deserve the help even if I'm poor at asking questions.

Comment: As a sidenote, vandalizing your question isn't going to get you a better reception here, or on main.  In general, if you approach Meta with an open mind, you'll get a much better response.  Calling votes you disagree with ridiculous, and not being receptive to being wrong will generally end in a less than stellar result.

Comment: *"Actually, if anyone tried the code I posted, it highlights the exact error"* People with lots of experience are offering, *for free*, to help you solve your programming problems. People who could charge upwards of a hundred or more per hour for consultation. It's actually kind of rude to not provide them with enough information to answer your question. And not only that, *it's going to decrease the likelihood that you get a quick, valid answer to your question*. It is to **everyone's** benefit you don't leave out important information like that in your questions. Questions. Question.

Comment: @Will Rude?  I have over a decade professional experience MYSELF.  I could charge that amount...  I DID provide a FULL EXAMPLE and DESCRIBED MY EXACT PROBLEM.  I just don't understand people who are saying this.

Comment: "doesn't want to work" is not an exact description, all caps or not all caps. If you don't understand that, after a decade of dealing with similar issues, then you're on your own.

Comment: @Will Is it not obvious that the fact it doesn't compile was the problem?  I wanted someone to suggest some workarounds for what I described using some syntactical flare.  I give up on SO tbh.

Comment: @DanRayson It is _never_ wrong to be clear about it. For one, it may not be clear upfront that there's a compilation error. And most importantly, the concrete error message from the compiler is actually useful for those reading the question and to those who are actively seeking to write an answer.

Comment: For your information, it was not obvious/clear to me that the problem was that it doesn't compile.

Comment: @AndréKool I will make attempts to be more clear about the fact something doesn't compile, which was just an example of what I was trying to acheive, and that I'd like something that does compile as answer.  This is 100% obvious to me.  I'd say you've not given it the time to know what my question was, no attempt made to understand it.

Comment: Even "doesn't compile" isn't specific enough. Always, always include the precise error message (copy/pasted rather than a summary of it) - whether that's an exception or a compile-time error. Make it as easy as possible for people to help you.

Comment: @DanRayson _" I'd say you've not given it the time to know what my question was, no attempt made to understand it."_ Given the enormous amount of questions and the few amount of potential answerers (as in, the experts of the question's domain), it is more efficient that the former group actually employs [as much research effort as possible](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1233251) in their questions. On the opposite spectrum, if the latter group requires a high amount of effort to understand a question, that is a sign of a low quality question.

Comment: @E_net4 So you saying you'd rather not read my question?  If my question has subtleties, if it's close to other questions but not quite the same and I have described that, and I've provided a full working example of the code, and you STILL can't understand it... I'd rather you not answer the question and not presume you understand enough to down-vote it.  (I say "you", I mean the third-party "you", not you specifically :))  I DID put effort into it, and all my colleagues here at work agree that they understand my question.  It's SO, and it's over-ego'd users, that are making my butt hurt.

Comment: @DanRayson Let's adjust that tone, shall we? ;) I'm not implying that our users should not seek to understand their questions, but that the task of making a clear and useful question is ultimately on the asker. It might seem clear to your local group (colleagues, workplace fellows, etc.), but they also might have a closer context to your work, whereas experienced developers might encounter additional ambiguities. While I'm in no position to assess this particular question, I would like you to understand that this is not a matter of condescendence, and feedback should be assumed in good faith.

Comment: @E_net4 I think you're right about the "experienced developers might encounter additional ambiguities" bit - All this experience has taught me is that even when I put effort into making the question as unambiguous and clear as possible, I still can't achieve the standard expected.  That's my position unfortunately.  Even after 10 years professional experience  myself, I still fall below the bar.  I really don't see any other way than to post "bad" questions, and hope for answers before it gets closed.

Comment: While I can sympathize with getting a rough reception...I can't really support posting a bad question and hoping you get an answer.  It shows a lack of respect for the community, because you know full well you're not meeting the bar, and you post it anyways.  If you want help improving your question, you need to be receptive to learning, not discounting criticism as ridiculous and the whims of, "over-ego'd users".

Comment: @fbueckert I fully understand what you're saying, and I would say the same thing to others.  However, I completely disagree with the reasons given to close the question, and can logically point out the flaws in their arguments.  It's not about the rough reception, it's about the close votes being completely and utterly wrong.

Comment: Well, duplicates are a common occurrence.  If you don't believe the question is actually a duplicate, the onus is on you to spell out how it's not.  If you have done so, and the question is still closed...then you need to be receptive to it actually being a duplicate.

Comment: @fbueckert I feel like you're asking me to be receptive to falsehoods.  The community can be wrong, just look at democracy...

Comment: I feel like you're not being receptive at all.  You're continuing to deface your question in your struggle to be right.  You need to be able to acknowledge that you might actually be wrong.  Until you're able to do that, you're going to keep getting the same rough reception.  And...you yourself voted to close it.  So...I'm confused what you expect this struggle to accomplish.

Comment: @fbueckert Admittedly I became frustrated and began lashing out, including defacing my own post.  I regret that.  I acknowledge I could be wrong, but when I see evidence to the contrary, I'm obviously going to side with the evidence.  I'm not being receptive, because that's my entire point!  I disagree with the close votes, and have reasons for disagreeing with them.  Like, they're not true, at all, not in the slightest.  "unverifiable code" -> I gave a 100% working example, and a 100% known NOT working example.  It was clear to people who gave it the time.

Comment: @fbueckert I should point out that there were 2 very good answers to the question too, SOME people thought the question was fine...

Comment: It was closed as a duplicate.  That means the question was already asked, and answered. What answers you have don't come into the decision making process.  But none of that changes the fact that you *yourself* voted to close your question.  I don't know if you chose the duplicate, or a different reason, but you still voted to close it.  So...I'm not sure what you expect the community to do.

Comment: @fbueckert I was hoping the community would simply recognise the problem, i.e. that the close votes were simply unfounded.  I voted to close my issue in anger.

Comment: What problem, though?  Does the duplicate not answer your question?  It leads back to an answer from Jon Skeet, of all people, from nine years ago.  That seems like a pretty good solution, so I'm not seeing a problem that needs resolving here.  At best, it shouldn't be a duplicate chain.  You asked a question, you got pointed at a question that already had answers.  That's the point of duplicates.

Comment: @fbueckert The question does not duplicate, because I asked for a very specific thing, and in a newer version of the language (as mentioned in the tags of the post, admittedly hidden away).  The essence of the question (in hindsight) is that subclasses of the `Enum` type cannot have extended functionality...  Nothing to do with "Enum type constraints in C#" which was the other question.  My question also highlighted an issue I have with a lack of understanding of Types and Instances when working with Enums.  Again, the answers of the other post were outdated and not geared to my question.

Comment: @fbueckert I should point out that I'd considered and read all possible duplicates before posting...

Comment: Don't you think that clarifying your question would be a good idea, then?  Being specific in what you found, and why it didn't work helps everybody; you, readers, and curators. Just saying previous answers are for older versions doesn't do anything; if it doesn't work, you have to say so, and tell us *why* it doesn't work.  We can't read your mind, and you can't expect others to do so.

Comment: Your recent edit on the question is not appropriate and will not contribute to your goals. In order for the question to be properly reconsidered for reopening, it must explain why the duplicate target does not answer it. It must _not_ be a plain rant, that can actually backfire.

Comment: I understand both of your comments.  Thanks.

Comment: I have updated/edited my original post on SO.  I'm hoping this is more understandable.  I've taken on board that I cannot blame everyone else.

Comment: Hey, look at that!  You got your question reopened!  That sounds like the system works.  Glad there was a positive outcome for you.

Comment: @fbueckert Someone may come along and actually put that as an answer!  All's well that ends well.

Answer (score -23, accepted):

#### You are not alone.

The suppression of the new site members is an old and long-standing problem of the Stack Exchange network. It is not a new phenomenon, it exists long, long ago, since the first Irc channels and Usenet groups.

The difference in our case:

- Stack Overflow has a reputation system, which means here you *can* do against the phenomenon - the last really useful reputation-bound privilege happens at 3000 (cast close and reopen votes). If you feel yourself suppressed, collect the 3k ASAP and start to help yourself, and others. Others with much more rep, have only a little bit more privileges as a 3k user.
- The Stack Exchange is a profit-oriented company in the U.S., it lives from the market, it has to produce good business results every year, and its top product, making it world-known is the Stack Overflow. An old member of an ancient Usenet group can be antagonistic with anybody, his living is independent from that. The SE (company) can't. The new code of conduct is likely only the first step.

*The site network needs you.*

*Get to 3k, and start to review!*

Comment: At most, the user would be able to cast a reopen vote. Other than that, I fail to understand the reasoning here, since no privilege can make a user reject close votes.

Comment: @E_net4 1) From 350 rep, you can cast reopen votes to your own posts. 2) From 3000 rep, you can cast reopen votes to the posts of *others*. 3) A post reopen requires 5 reopen votes, so 5 unfair post handlers could save daily 40 questions.

Comment: You actually mean [250 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes), but doesn't that drive your argument even further away from what you're defending? If the point here is to show disagreement with a specific closure of their own question, the user doesn't need the cast close votes and reopen votes privilege.

Answer (score 9):

In most cases, it takes five >3k rep users to close a question. One close vote such as the one you got just sends it to the Close Votes queue, where experienced users will be able to see whether or not it is actually closeable.

The exceptions are:

- A gold tag badge holder may singlehandedly close a question *as a duplicate*, as @Patrice mentioned. This is called "dupehammering". This doesn't apply in your case - you got a "regular", non-dupehammer close vote.
- A diamond moderator may singlehandedly close a question. This doesn't apply either, if a moderator had closevoted the question would have been closed already.

Answer (score -18):

I'm going to answer my own question.

Shrug is all you can do, the system is good, but not perfect, deal with it.

It's my opinion that the fact the question now has 4 close votes, on a question that really is unique and relevant, is just stupid.

The system is broken.  I wanted to ask a question, and I got a good answer, that much is OK.  But, if the close votes had happened faster, I wouldn't have found the site useful at all.  I'm also convinced that my question will be relevant to other people, as I myself have wanted this question answering on multiple occasions.

-20 on my question here also?  Aren't I showing initiative on asking how to improve?  This isn't a rant... this is a legitimate concern about the way this site behaves.  I'm considering not posting any more question or answers due to bad community "sniping", rejection of good questions/answers, etc, all because people have been given a voice.

That voice is TOO LOUD!

Comment: I feel that the downvotes in your meta question are unnecessary, but still that doesn't make this "answer" ok.

Comment: Also, since you are new in meta, be aware that voting in meta is a much more relaxed business, with no impact whatsoever in your reputation. Low question traffic, demanding users, no consequences... that gives you many more votes (in any direction) that you'd get in the main site.

Comment: my goal here is to highlight the mistreatment of legitimate users, via the tools this site provides.  The close vote mechanic works to belittle the question askers, I know, because I feel belittled.  p.s.  Interesting that meta doesn't go towards score, didn't know that.

Comment: All non fraudulent users are _legitimate_, so I do not understand that. And neither voting nor close-voting should be considered "mistreatment". Other users are entitled to their own opinions, and to use the site tools to express it. The fact that you do not agree with it doesn't make that opinion a mistreatment. It doesn't seem that you are open to the possibility that something was actually in need of improvement in your post. I would advise to reconsider that attitude.

Comment: Also please note your question has been marked a duplicate. The way I like to view a closure like that is _"You can find your answer here"_

Comment: Your question has a score of 3 and got closed as a duplicate, which just points you to **additional answers**. Do you feel the answers at the duplicate don't answer your question?

Comment: _"Aren't I showing initiative on asking how to improve?"_ You didn't really ask how to improve, to be fair, you asked what you can do about a "ridiculous" close vote. Sure, you asked if you're missing something and if you're wrong... But if you meant something other than _"Was I wrong that there is nothing I can do? Am I missing a way to deal with this close vote?"_ then you'll need to clarify. (I too feel that the downvotes are a bit overkill on this question, but voting is _very_ different on Meta. Look at the "What's Meta?" page in the [help] to learn more.)

Comment: Don't worry on that. They can downvote you, but they can't silent you. The SE has clear rules, what is allowed and what is not, and we have our place in it. Just post, review, and represent your view on the meta, continuously. This is allowed, even probably liked by the SE, despite that it is disliked many many here.