# Request to re-open a simple Verilog question

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

[$display vs $strobe vs $monitor in verilog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32832104/display-vs-strobe-vs-monitor-in-verilog)

Verilog is very much on-topic as a language, and I see nothing to suggest this question is off-topic. A [closure reason given by dave_59](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32832104/display-vs-strobe-vs-monitor-in-verilog#comment53506952_32832104)

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we shouldn't have to read the manual for you. Please show what you have researched so far and still find confusing.

doesn't make sense given the plethora of simple but unambiguous questions about basic concepts in other languages.

Edit: Sadly a valuable online resource, including an answer with 5 upvotes, has been lost due to the question being closed. It is available for posterity here https://web.archive.org/web/20161125105302/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32832104/display-vs-strobe-vs-monitor-in-verilog

Comment: Well, you can edit your question to make it _Request to undelete simple Verilog question_... The question has been deleted now...

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I have no idea why this question was just deleted...

Comment: That often happens when bringing questions to meta. The [meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269350/7296893) kicked in, and that often leads to downvotes and delete votes. I'd like it more if people would've waited a bit for consensus here, but it's how it often goes.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: _"and that often leads to downvotes and delete votes."_ correction: it leads to more critical attention, which can also include upvotes, re-open votes, and undelete votes. Please don't only mention one side of the meta effect.

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm just stating it's not unusual that this happened, and provided a link to a longer explanation why and how. Note I also didn't talk about close votes, since none were cast on this specific question due to the meta effect.

Comment: I realize that, it's just that too often, only the negative side is mentioned (even if only part of it)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I've posted an internet archive link

Comment: Great, now we have a web archive link that links to a copy of documentation that links to a web archive link...

Comment: @qwr `Sadly a valuable online resource, including an answer with 5 upvotes,`  that  answer has **10 upvotes** [check the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jq7Ff.png)

Comment: @NileshRathod It's a shame people in the StackOverflow community choose to delete a clearly useful resource instead of trying to improve it.

Comment: So, _how_ would you improve the question, @qwr?

Comment: @Cerbrus if the issue is that "no effort" was put into the question, then adding example output or citing some documentation I believe improves the question. Of course, I cannot improve it now.

Comment: Adding example output or citing documentation would answer the question, so that shouldn't be in the question, that should be in an answer (which it already was). So we're still left with a low quality question. Any other suggestions to __improve the question__ without answering it?

Comment: I disagree that answers the question. It may be that even with example output, some doubt remains, and so needs to be cleared up.

Comment: If you believe a useful q&a could be posted on this topic, post another question yourself. A better one, hopefully. You can even post an answer directly.

Comment: @qwr You have no way to delete your this question, but you can make my answer undeletable by accepting it. I suggest to do that. The site strongly needs our view.

Comment: @qwr Don't hope a deletion... your this question won't be ever deleted, it is nearly sure, exactly on the same reason, why are you hoping its deletion. You can't defend your MSO profile, but you can fight back. Accept!

Comment: Note: Accepting an answer won't actually make an answer immune to deletion.  Users with 20K can still vote to delete any answer at -1 or below.  Acceptance would do nothing constructive in this case.

Comment: You should also know that accepting an answer does not make it the consensus, or make it the policy going forward.  Accepting such a heavily downvoted answer does nothing but seem like sour grapes.

Comment: I picked the answer that I believe most accurately answers my original post.

Comment: @qwr: You picked the answer that echoes ___your opinion___, ignoring what meta (votes) tells you is the correct answer.

Comment: And since the OP isn't considering the input of the community to be of any value, I'm close-voting this as _"This question does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community."_

Comment: @Cerbrus none of the other answers address why the question was deleted, which is what I changed my original post to after the events that happened a couple minutes after asking my question.

Comment: @qwr that still doesn't explain why you accepted the most downvoted answer on this question. That looks like _"I don't care what the community thinks, This answer echoes my opinion."_

Comment: Again I accepted the answer because it provides the clearest reasoning (in my view) addressing the deletion. So perhaps this question is better off as two, one about closure and one about deletion.

Comment: There, I added a more neutral explanation about the deletion to my answer.

Comment: Oh, @qwr, NEVER edit a question in such a way that it changes the entire meaning of the question. If you want to discuss the deletion of the question, ask a new question. This was originally about re-opening the question. Changing that to a request to undelete it invalidates existing answers, by ___completely___ changing the context of this question.

Comment: @Cerbrus "***completely***" changes it? Really? He wants the question open and undeleted. His edits simply reflected a change in the circumstances since the question was first asked, caused by *you deleting the question he's asking about*. I don't see how that invalidates the existing answers at all.

Comment: Can we have a mod reopen this? The question on main is notionally locked until the dispute about it here on Meta is resolved; that clearly can't happen if the Meta question is closed. Also, the justification for closure of this Meta question was - as I understand it - that since the main question got deleted, the Meta question could no longer be "reproduced" due to the change in circumstances; with the Main question undeleted, that justification is gone.

Comment: No, this was closed because the OP was not _"open to input or discussion"_ unless that input echoes his opinion, as you can clearly see with the accepted answer here.

Comment: I was very willing to engage in other's answers in the comment section, irrespective of which I accepted. Also given Mark Amery's excellent answer, I may change my accepted answer.

Comment: @Cerbrus The fact that nobody in fact succeeded at changing the OP's mind doesn't mean they weren't open to discussion; it just means they still disagree with you. But even if that weren't the case, who cares if qwr is personally closed-minded about this question? We can have a discussion anyway; it's not like qwr controls what we're allowed to say here just because they posted the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I agree that this should be reopened.

I'm not a Verilog expert, but so far *nobody* criticising this question has claimed that the question's [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32854465/1709587), which is a grand total of around 7 sentences plus a code snippet, is anything less than a correct and entirely complete answer to the question that was asked. I'm therefore presuming, until somebody claims otherwise, that it *is* in fact correct and complete.

I've also taken the time to acquire a copy of [IEEE 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/standard/1800-2012.html), the standard cited by that same accepted answer. It takes *10 pages* to cover the behaviour of these three functions.

There have been, essentially, two arguments given for why this question deserves closure. The first, quoted in this Meta question, was basically that it was asking for something trivially looked up in "the manual". But as best I can tell, there *is* no single official manual for Verilog, only a standard. That standard, as I mentioned, takes 10 pages to cover this material, and is also behind a paywall, so it is hardly possible to answer this question with a trivial lookup. Other references I can find publicly available via Google, like https://accellera.org/images/downloads/standards/v-ams/VAMS-LRM-2-4.pdf, also fail to clearly and succinctly describe the differences between these functions in a single place. As such, I think that the assertion that the question is trivially answerable by using official sources (whether or not that's a valid justification for closing questions in the first place) is not actually true.

The *second* argument against the question is that it's too broad. There have been essentially two variants of this argument made. One is advanced by Nicol Bolas, in [his answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379880/1709587). As I understand it, he considers an analogy to two substantially different but easily-confused functions in OpenGL (an API he knows well), and argues that a question asking what the difference between them is would be unhelpful because to answer it *completely* he'd essentially have to regurgitate the full content of the documentation of each of those individual functions, providing no value-add over the reader just reading those documentation pages themselves. That's all well and good, as it concerns his hypothetical case. But I think it is a mistake to casually assume, as he does, that this is an inherent and inevitable problem with *"what is the difference between these things"* questions. It is perfectly possible for two functions to be almost exactly identical in their behaviour, modulo one tiny difference, but for their official documentation to describe their behaviour in a way that does not make that clear. This appears to be such a case; as such, I don't think Nicol's argument applies.

The second variant of the argument for the question being Too Broad is that [the fact that the standard takes a lot of pages to describe these functions' behaviour proves that the question is very broad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379851/request-to-re-open-a-simple-verilog-question#comment668461_379853). I think this is patently silly. The fact one source spends many words describing something does not mean that it innately requires many words to describe, and the fact that we do in fact have an answer that is only a few sentences long seems to prove that.

In summary, the question looks to my inexpert eye like it provides value to Verilog programmers by succinctly offering information that is hard to extract from the official standard, and that none of the arguments for its closure survive scrutiny. I usually refrain from pitching in on moderating questions in technologies that I don't use or understand, but since in this case many of the close-voters *also* don't have any subject-matter expertise (and since the [verilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/verilog) community probably isn't big enough to reopen this on its own), I'm comfortable arguing for reopening. Maybe, in my ignorance of Verilog, I'm misjudging this - but if so, I haven't seen a persuasive argument of that yet.

---

Secondly, I'm annoyed by the attempts to shut down discussion on this Meta thread, which took two forms:

- Voting to delete the accepted answer. I don't agree with it either, but I agree [with Cody Gray](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379851/request-to-re-open-a-simple-verilog-question#comment668101_379858) that voting to delete perfectly coherently-argued opinions because you disagree with them is an abuse of delete votes. The proper recourse was to argue against it, not to delete it.
- Voting to close the question itself. There were two justifications given: the stock reason that the question "does not seek input and discussion", and, during the time that the question on the main site was deleted, that this Meta question asked about a situation that "can no longer be reproduced", on the grounds that a deleted question can't be reopened.

  This all seems very silly to me. Posting a Meta thread arguing for taking some action on a specific question is perfectly legitimate and done frequently. It seems to me that this question seeks input just as much as any other such question does - and, indeed, that it has attracted *a great deal* of input.

  Arguing that the Meta question deserves closure due to the main question's deletion also strikes me as a use of closure that we shouldn't accept. It's normal, and perfectly fine, that the status of a question on main changes over the course of a discussion about it on Meta. That isn't a reason for closure, and indeed there's nothing at all specific to *this* question about that particular line of argument. Those who voted to close the Meta question on that basis are effectively arguing for a system that allows any three people to halt *any* Meta discussion about reopening a question: you just delete the question from main that's being discussed, revert any edits on Meta acknowledging that this has happened and [criticise them as being a wrongful use of editing powers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379851/request-to-re-open-a-simple-verilog-question#comment668343_379851) for invalidating the existing discussion, and vote to close the Meta question on the grounds that the circumstances have changed.

  This is silly. The discussion about the merits of the Verilog question was not invalidated by its deletion. If we accept that it was, we permit a trivial tactic for any three people on the pro-closure side to auto-win any discussion about reopening a question and forbid anyone from ever arguing with them about it again - a tactic that clearly some users are in fact willing to deploy. That's stupid.

Comment: I must object to that last paragraph in this answer. I never called the edits to this meta question "Abusive". This question was originally about re-opening an _old_ question that was closed shortly after it was posted. Imo, the (un-)deletion of said question is a completely different subject. Answers that explained why the question _shouldn't_ be re-opened were no longer applicable after the subject was changed to the (un-)deletion.

Comment: @Cerbrus You didn't use the word "abusive", true, but you responded to the edit by saying that they should "NEVER" (sic - shouting in the original) use their edit powers in such a way. I don't see much distinction.

Answer (score 7):

> the plethora of simple but unambiguous questions about basic concepts in other languages

Stack Overflow does not function on historical precedent, but on what the rules are right now. What was on-topic a year ago may be off-topic today.

I think you'll find that the questions you're using as examples were asked a looong time ago. The ever-increasing massive influx of new users asking terribly poor questions has required that the rules for asking questions be increasingly tightened up, which is why that question was closed and deleted.

Comment: I still do not see what is poor about the question. It is a common verilog question posed clearly.

Answer (score 7):

I know pretty much nothing about Verilog, so allow me to restate your issue using a system I understand, so that I can better explain why this Verilog question is not really a good one.

In OpenGL, there are two concepts that are frequently misunderstood but are related: vertex array objects (VAO) and "vertex buffer objects" (VBOs, which are not really a thing, but have been called a thing enough that they have become a thing despite the API not making them a thing).

So, one could conceivably ask the question "what is the difference between a VAO and a VBO?" However, that doesn't make for a good question. Part of the reason is that the answer would really just be a restatement of everything on [this page](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification) and [this page](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object). But a more substantive reason is that such a restatement would likely not help users. After all, both of those pages exist, so why aren't they helping users?

An educated user who is confused about these two things is almost never confused about the basic concepts themselves, but certain *specific interactions* between them. In my long experience with these questions, the confusion ultimately boils down to one or more of the following specific points:

1. A failure to understand how a buffer object gets hooked up to a VAO. This is because the OpenGL API is... utterly absurd in this regard, to the point where, if I didn't know better, I would claim that it was deliberately designed to confused people.
2. A failure to fully understand what it means to "bind an object" in OpenGL.
3. A failure to understand how objects get created and filled with data in OpenGL.

I could answer the general "difference between VAO and VBO" question in a way that covers point 1, but leaves points 2 and 3 assumed (indeed, one of the pages I linked to does precisely that). Thus, users who are confused by either of those points don't gain anything from my perfectly valid answer.

That's the problem with general "what is the difference between these things" questions: different people will be confused in different ways. In order for such questions to produce good, actionable answers, they *must* be relatively narrowly scoped. And the best way to do that is to explain what *specifically* you are confused about.

If you understand something about these three Verilog concepts, but are confused about how certain aspects of them interact, then *that* is what you should be asking about. Don't ignore your current understanding; use it to fuel your question. And if you have no current understanding... then *fix that* before asking a question.

Comment: The trouble with this answer is that the analogy doesn't seem to match the actual question at stake. You imply - by comparison with a similar-sounding hypothetical question where it'd be *true* - that to explain the difference between the functions being discussed one would have to fully restate the documentation describing each of them. But in *this* case, the official standard takes 10 pages to describe these functions, but the answer here uses *one sentence* per function to describe how their behaviour differs. And nobody here has yet claimed that that answer is missing a single detail.

Comment: I feel this answer misses the point. The information in question is not easily available (not a simple manual read). All three functions have very similar functionality. If the questions would have been asked like "in which situation should one use $display over $ strobe or $monitor, because in my test cases they produced the same code, and the 10 page long very dry and technical description is hard to understand for a non-native speaker", than the question would have been focused enough, which was the reason of closing it.

Comment: The analogy seems wrong.  It is more like what is the difference between `printf()`, and `fprintf()`.  The concepts ($strobe, $monitor and $display) are not un-related.  They are all related to debugging/simulation of verilog.

Answer (score 6):

> *"doesn't make sense given the plethora of simple but unambiguous questions about basic concepts in other languages."*

If someone else jumps into a sewage processing plant, would you?

The fact there are other examples of low quality questions out there, doesn't mean this one should be re-opened.

That question was closed 2 weeks after it was asked and it didn't really add any value to the site.

Preferably, Verilog's documentation should be a search result instead of that question, since that's typical documentation material. The answer was for a large part just an copy-paste from said documentation.

---

The question deletion is due to the [Meta Effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect).

This meta question drew more attention to that question, resulting in more users taking a critical look at the value of that question.

Enough users deemed it necessary to delete that question, and so it was.

Contrary to wat some would have you believe, this has nothing to do with "Malice" or "privilege misuse". The question wasn't good. The answer wasn't very good, and there is no historical significance in an answer that can trivially be found in documentation.

---

The post has just been undeleted, closed as "Too broad" and locked, by a moderator.

Basically, it's back to where it was before this meta question. Let's leave it at that.

Comment: So do you consider questions that can be answered by the documentation off-topic? What about this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do

Comment: @qwr: That question is 10 years old. If it were asked today, it would probably be closed as "off-topic" (or a duplicate).

Comment: There is nothing to suggest these questions are analogous to a "sewage processing plant". Can you point me to a specific reason this question is off-topic?

Comment: I'm not comparing _that question_ to a processing plant. I'm explaining that your _"There are other questions like it"_ reasoning doesn't work.

Comment: What part of Stack Overflow suggests answering by largely citing documentation is frowned upon?

Comment: @qwr You are focusing on the answer. IMO, you should be focusing on the question if you want to discuss its closure/deletion.

Comment: It's not _"citing documentation"_ that's problematic. That question is nothing more than a _"What's this button do? And that one?"_ There's no effort, no research, no problem statement, nothing. It's simply not a quality question.

Comment: @qwr "What part of Stack Overflow suggests answering by largely citing documentation is frowned upon?" The fact that the first, and most prominent part of the "how to ask" page states that questions are expected to be well researched.  A question easily found in the documentation and effectively answered by it *is not a well researched question*, and is not a useful addition to this site.

Comment: *"The answer was for a large part just an copy-paste from said documentation."* - wait, what? I checked the standard (it's pirateable via Sci-Hub) and as far as I can see nothing at all in the answer is copied from the standard.

Comment: @MarkAmery: Okay, maybe not literal copy-paste, but those bullet points are exactly what documentation exists for.

Comment: @Cerbrus *What* documentation? The standard? It's not even freely available. And even with it (after acquiring it through either payment or piracy), it takes *10 pages* to describe the functions being talked about in this question; I haven't read them, but it'd probably take a typical reader a good half hour to wade through it all, and I'm not certain if the differences between the functions would be clear even then.

Comment: @MarkAmery You're making it sound as if the question is incredibly broad.

Comment: The more reason to keep it closed / deleted.

Comment: @fbueckert The fact that the *standard* takes 10 pages to describe the functions does not mean that it *actually requires* 10 pages to describe the differences between them. I haven't seen anybody claim that the answer there - which describes the difference in behaviour with a single sentence per function - is anything less than a fully correct and complete description of the differences. The fact that it manages to do that in three sentences proves the question is not broad; the fact that in doing so it spares the reader from reading 10 pages of the standard means it has value.

Comment: @MarkAmery What you had been describing, though, sounded very broad indeed, to properly answer the question.  A summary can provide value, sure, and that seems to be an argument worthy of mention.  I don't see that in any of the answers, though.

Answer (score -21):

<sup>Update 1: Question was undeleted, clarified/fixed, and it is about to be reopened. Problem solved. Thank for everybody the undelete votes and the fixups!</sup>

<sup>Update 2: The question was deleted again... **Please vote to undelete.**</sup>

The question is now deleted, but it is still visible [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20161125105302/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32832104/display-vs-strobe-vs-monitor-in-verilog).

Seeing that 1 hour ago you requested a reopen, it is reasonable to estimate, that the question was deleted with the intention to make this reopen nearly impossible.

The question was unclear and too broad, despite that the answer - with its +10<sup>1</sup> vote - was not. We could talk about, if its closure was okay.

Its deletion was a clear violation, a privilege misuse, because it destroyed a +10 answer. As the relevant [rule](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) says:

> Before voting to delete, please check whether there are any good answers; if so, then the question should be flagged for moderator attention as a potential merge candidate. We don't like to lose great answers!

The delete voters intentionally violated this rule. With it, the site lost a great answer. From the phenomenon, you can read more in my [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373357/1783163) post.

The correct behavior had been to flag the question for a moderator lock as "historical significance". I.e. it was ontopic at the moment of its posting, but it is not ontopic now, because the site rules became always more strict.

<sup>1</sup><sub>The archive.org link says only +5, but @yivi mentions +10.</sub>

Comment: A couple inaccuracies in this answer: The question was not posted by the OP. The answer was scored 10, not 5. The voters may or may have not violated a rule, but you can't say speak for their intentions, unless you can read minds.

Comment: @yivi 1. The original question was created many years ago. 2. This meta post was created since around 1 hour. 3. The original question is now deleted. <- Yes, I think this is an enough strong estimate from the intentions of the delete voters.

Comment: @peterh Do you have a merge candidate, or do you think there is a good, non-closed merge candidate? I very much doubt the mods would appreciate someone following that rule for questions like this, the flag would not be actionable. If you think users are abusing privileges, you can always flag for moderator attention and explain the situation to have a moderator review it. I'm 99.9% sure the moderator won't see this as abuse.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I can't flag a deleted question, because I can't see them. The rules were violated, it is clear, *"We don't like to lose great answers!"*, yes do you see that? You are not allowed to delete a question with a highly upvoted answer without a *really* serious reason. This rule was violated. Also the motive of the delete voters is clear from the timeline of the events.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Btw, as we both know very well, despite the rule violation, mods typically don't intervene in such cases on political reasons. They simply won't conflict with with at least 3, at least 10k users. This is why deleting useful, valuable content is de jure forbidden, but de facto allowed.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188012/discussion-on-answer-by-peterh-request-to-undelete-simple-verilog-question).

Comment: **Attention delete voters:** regardless of your opinions with respect to the deletion under discussion, *this answer is an answer* to the Meta question that was asked, and as such, should not be deleted. That is absolutely a mis-use of your delete-vote privileges. You are welcome to disagree, and you are welcome to downvote, but you should not vote to delete Meta answers because you disagree with them.

Comment: @CodyGray: Can we delete-vote meta answers because they're offensive or lack arguments to back up their claims of "abuse" and assumptions about intentions? ;-)

Comment: @Cerbrus they’re our votes, they’ve drilled it into us that we can do as we see fit with them, as long as there’s no malice, so delete away!

Comment: @Clive: I believe that liberty only covers up/downvotes.

Comment: @Cerbrus Meh, tripe is tripe; it should be removed regardless of arbitrary labels IMO. If this guy has the right to spout this provacative, passive aggressive nonsense, I have an equal right to get rid of it. I certainly won’t stop voting to delete this rubbish :)

Comment: @Cerbrus you directly insult me in your post, how's that for offensive?

Comment: @qwr: that was never my intent. What in my answer insults you? I'll see if I can re-word it to be less offensive.

Comment: @Clive: you can start at the question being discussed ;-)

Comment: @Cerbrus I was literally just about to but qwr beat me to it by editing about 21 seconds before. And now it’s, while not the most amazing question under the sun, probably not worthy of deletion anymore for me

Comment: @Clive: Hm, now the accepted answer doesn't completely answer the question any more...

Comment: @Cerbrus Does it? I confess I don't know the technology. That's a shame. I'm going to leave that side of the voting to more qualified people then I think

Comment: @Clive There are various tools and softwares to create circuits in verilog, and then emulate them. The technology is imho wonderful, something on the border of the programming and electronics. If you see verilog questions about to close, I suggest rather try to reach their migration to the [Electronics SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Cerbrus Both the question and the accepted answer is about the time when the question was yet deleted. I think extending the post with a preabmel clarifying this is enough.

Comment: @peterh: Then the OP completely changed the meaning of this question, invalidating existing answers. Such edits are usually reverted.

Comment: @Clive: Looking at it again, the edit to this question completely changed the context of the question and invalidated existing answers. In other words, it should've been a new question. I reverted that edit.