# Someone is taking some liberties I don't think they should

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-answers

[Inserting HTML into other HTML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55736038/inserting-html-into-other-html-files/55736083)

3 answers were given that did answer the OP question and then they received downvotes (all 3), and then just a min ago someone started deleting the answer with no explanation.

Comment: So...what would make that question even *remotely* on topic in the first place?

Comment: The only ones who can delete answers are users with 20K, or moderators.  What, "liberties" are being taken?

Comment: @fbueckert:  The OP's answer along with a few others were deleted.

Comment: Idk it threw me off a bit im still getting used to how things work here but the question was pretty simple and could use some editing but I understood exactly what he needed and what issue he was running into its a very common issue new developers run into so I provided a solution as well as 3 others and then someone comes downvotes and deletes the post....thats honestly kinda hurtful

Comment: It's also a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27662098/include-header-html-to-include-multiple-html-pages (and 3 more linked within the question itself)

Comment: @Makoto I get that.  But I'm wondering how that qualifies as a liberty.  Those privileges are granted because those users are trusted.  Doesn't seem like a liberty to me.

Comment: "Pretty simple" and "understood exactly what he needed" and "what issue he was running into" aren't justifications for topicality.  What I'm seeing is a question which is too broad which was inviting all *sorts* of answers.  So I ask again - what would make that question even *remotely* on-topic in the first place?

Comment: @fbueckert:  There was a flare-up with a new diamond moderator and their choice of deleting an answer.  Some saw this as an atypical use of power.  I won't indicate if this is the same case circumstance, but it's *similar*.

Comment: Perhaps I dont fully understand what is on-topic so I will look into that but downvotes and deleting answer should not be okay especially when the answers were all valid answers that could have solved the OP problem

Comment: You submitted a PHP solution. Ok, well, the OP didn't specify php, but, yeah, your solution would work. So would a python solution. or node.js, or any number of languages that could be used as a webserver. that's... quite broad. The OP needed to specify either A: client-side only, or B: which backend they want to work with. Then we could have closed it as a dupe.

Comment: Okay the javascript solution was also downvoted and deleted @KevinB Ive seen questions get put on hold but this is the first time ive seen someone delete the answers

Comment: They also didn't specify JS. They didn't specify anything, that's the problem.

Comment: @CoderJoe JavaScript answer was deleted by author (who also added "javascript" tag to question - which may or may not what OP is interested in, OP only specified HTML5). And with significantly broadened question after edit (asking about perf) that answer no longer provided an answer... (Obviously no idea who/why exactly downvoted it)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I did not know that he had tagged the question with javascript but I know that it Cody gray who deleted my answer

Comment: @CoderJoe I don't think ability to see edit history is gated on any reputation... Could not you just check https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55736038/revisions ?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yea I can see it now I just didnt notice it at the time

Comment: 1. Your question was unfairly closed and downvoted and deleted, it should have been a reference post; 2. The reviewers and voters of this community are often very hostile, sadly you seem finding one of our worst faces, just after beginning 3; Please read my [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373357/1783163) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373357/1783163) previous answers.

Comment: @peterh I see the discussion it takes 5 people to close something is this just for post or answers too from what I seen it only takes one person no flags https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373318/10798916

Comment: @CoderJoe I can't really understand your comment. Colubia said the truth in his answer, but it was not the essence of the question. The question was about the hostility what the OP experienced.

Answer (score 11):

**Just because the answers <s>were</s> had a chance of being valid doesn't mean the question was on-topic to begin with.**

It would behoove you to recognize that this question - and similar questions like it - are too broad because they are asking for an unbound data set.   That is to say, there are any number of ways that could've solved the OP's problem, yet they failed to provide any constraints or define what "solved" looked like.

For context, this is the full question:

> I am creating my first full website and am finding that the code is
>   getting quite long and unorganized.
>
> This is mostly due to duplicated code that must appear on every page.
>   For example, my navigation bar code must be put in every page on my
>   website.
>
> Is there a way to put this code in it's own separate file and simply
>   include the nav.html in each page?
>
> Is this common practice? Will I see any noticeable decrease or
>   increase in loading times?
>
> Thanks in advance

Code organization isn't a concrete or solved problem.  Templating *is*, which could've been a better angle for this question

**However**, there's no indication from the OP...

- ...how they're building their site in the first place
- ...if they're using a framework or template engine to begin with
- ...what they've actually attempted to do or what they're working with

...because if they *had*, then we could actually talk about concrete solutions instead of abstract, fuzzy solutions.

Given that your response leveraged PHP...

> You can do this by leveraging PHP
>
> 1. Create a folder called `includes` in this folder create a new file called `nav.php`
> 2. Now change any page that you will be calling this nav bar to have a `.php` file extension
> 3. Add the html you need to replicate to `includes/nav.php`
> 4. Now wherever you want to add the html write the following line
>
> ```
> <?php include("includes/nav.php"); ?>
> ```
>
> For more information you can see the docs here
>   https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

...you have no way of objectively saying if your solution would or would not work since **you don't know if the OP is using PHP from their given question.**

Comment: I get what your saying but according to another post on meta https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382775/when-should-i-flag-an-answer technical correctness is not something that mods delete a post for its a downvote not a deletion

Comment: @CoderJoe and that's why I hate that post. Whenever or not it meets our quality standards is what should be evaluated. That thing didn't.

Comment: Yes, but then again I see this from the "usefulness" or "harm" angle. I'm not justifying the mod's actions, but I see no cause to disagree with them. Those answers to me read like they don't contribute to a solution since the problem is ill defined.

Comment: meh, the question will be deleted along with the answers anyway. why care that it happened sooner? Now we don't have to deal with the possibility of someone upvoting the answers or bountying it to prevent deletion.

Comment: @CoderJoe note that mods have two sides - "generic exception handler without any domain knowledge but god power" and "expert in several technologies with extra power boosts" - it is ok if "expert in several technologies" part of a mod deletes completely incorrect post (there was post about it recently)

Comment: According to the help center the reasons why a post might be deleted still do not reflect on the actions...im not gonna keep rambling on about it because its honestly not worth it I just didnt agree with how that was handled

Comment: FWIW it's too broad because the problem they're trying to solve is actually a very large collection of problems presented as a single problem. Solutions to this one problem would actually entail a bunch of solutions to the smaller problems grouped together, and because all of these individual solutions can vary so greatly it leads to it being just too darn broad. All of this to say that there are any number of ways of solving pretty well any problem that could be presented here, but that doesn't in and of itself make those problems too broad. The problem is that it isn't truly one problem.